# How to remove a stripped nozzle

Tags: nozzle, creality-ender-5, repair

A few months ago I got an Ender 5 printer. After a few successful prints with only PLA, I started getting a lot of issues. The last time I came back after an hour and there was just a bird's nest around the nozzle.

I cleaned up all the PLA I could visibly see around the nozzle and the inside as much as I can tell. I decided to replace the nozzle, but when I tried to remove it, it was stuck.  All the wrenches I have couldn't hold it, and now it's stripped pretty smooth.

What options are left? Was there PLA stuck inside the hot bed that's holding the nozzle?  I heated it to printing levels to soften it but no luck.

Comment: Pics? You probably need to replace the block but it's not expensive or a big undertaking.

Comment: Try a pair of vise grip pliers, that should work. But as suggested, replace heater block and nozzle, see [this answer](/a/13642).